# Ruby on rails Many to many relationship with through for creating data using active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have looked into most of the question and answer related to this has_many :through relationship but i am not able to find any question that deals with has many :through with validation. I would be really glad if someone would help me with this validation issue i am having. 
Here is my models

```rb
class Dev < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :abbrev, uniqueness: true, presence: true

  has_many :social_dev
  has_many :social_ads, through: :social_dev
end
class SocialAds < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :social_dev, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :devs, through: :social_dev
  validates :devs, :presence => true
end
class SocialDev < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :social_ads
  belongs_to :dev
end
```

I am basically using rspec to create some test scenario for which i am trying to write a  active record. 
How can i create an active record which would allow me to create record in join table and in main table. Currently i am getting - Devs cannot be blank error.

```rb
 dev = Dev.find_by_name('Developer')

 SocialDev.create!(
   dev: dev,
   social_ads: SocialAds.create!(
     language: language,
     gender: gender,
     start_date: start_date,
     name: name,
     tax: tax,
     end_date: end_date    
  )
)
```

Comment: Show your current code that fails at validation.

Comment: @arieljuod I have added the code that is similar to what i am doing.  I might be entirely wrong as i real novice here. And I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to create the SocialAds before you actually set the SocialDev on it.

Try this:

```
dev = Dev.find_by_name('Developer')

# note it's a has_many, it should be plural
dev.social_devs.create(
  # note it's a "belongs_to", it should be singular
  social_ad: SocialAd.new(
    language: language,
    gender: gender,
    start_date: start_date,
    name: name,
    tax: tax,
    end_date: end_date 
  )
)
```

Now the SocialAd object will be validated when the SocialDev is being validated and not before.

Note that you are not following rails conventions for naming and it can also affect your validations:

- `SocialAd` instead of `SocialAds`
- `belongs_to :social_ad` instead of `belongs_to :social_ads`
- `has_many :social_devs` instead of `has_many :social_dev`

Answer (score 0):

You can create both the model and its join table records using rails' `create` method.

```
SocialAd.create(devs: Dev.where(name: "foo"))
```

Rails is smart enough to know that `devs` is a `has_many` association and it will create the corresponding `SocialDev` join records. It will also satisfy your `validates :devs, :presence => true` validation.